# QImage 16 bit grayscale with QQuickPaintedItem

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, rendering, qimage

I have unsigned 16 bit image data that I displayed by subclassing QQuickPaintedItem in Qt 5.12.3. I used QImage with Format_RGB32 and scaled the data from [0, 16383] to [0, 255] and set that as the color value for all three R,G,B. Now, I am using Qt 5.15.2 which has a QImage FORMAT_GrayScale16 that I'd like to use but for some reason the image is displayed incorrectly. The code I used to convert my unsigned 16 bit image data to QImage for both formats is shown below. The QQuickPaintedItem is a basic subclassing with `drawImage(window(), my_qimage);` that I pass the QImage as returned from the code below. Why is the new format not displaying correctly?

**Format_RGB32 method**

```cpp
QImage image(image_dim, QImage::Format_RGB32);
unsigned int pixel = 0;
for (uint16_t row = 0; row < nrow; row++) {
    uint *scanLine = reinterpret_cast<uint *>(image.scanLine(row));
    for (uint16_t col = 0; col < ncols; col++) {
        uint16_t value = xray_image.data()[pixel++]; // Get each pixel
        unsigned short color_value = uint16_t((float(value) / 16383) * 255.0f); // scale [0, 255]
        *scanLine++ = qRgb(int(color_value), int(color_value), int(color_value));
    }
}
return image;
```

[image: Format_RGB32]

**Format_Grayscale16 method**

```cpp
QImage image(image_dim, QImage::Format_Grayscale16);
unsigned int pixel = 0;
for (uint16_t row = 0; row < nrow; row++) {
    // **EDIT WRONG:** uint *scanLine = reinterpret_cast<uint *>(image.scanLine(row));
    uint16_t *scanLine = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t *>(image.scanLine(row));
    for (uint16_t col = 0; col < ncols; col++) {
        *scanLine++ = xray_image.data()[pixel++]; // Get each pixel
    }
}
return image;
```

[image: Format_Grayscale16]

Comment: Does this code compile? I have 5.15.2, and there is no QImage::data().

Comment: I am coping the data from a smart pointer vector `image.data()[pixel++]` so not a QImage data type.

Comment: I get a compiler warning with your code (though I had to make some assumptions), but...no matter. Have you tried QImage::convertToFormat()?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this line `*scanLine++ = image.data()[pixel++];`?

Comment: I'm assigning the pixel data from my vector into the qimage location. I did find a bug when I converted in that scanLine pointer was using 32 bit but I expected a 16 bit pointer. I updated this and I get a better image. I also found out that I did not convert my contrast filter to use the new 16 bit grayscale. I think in all, I found the problem and I am applying the fix to see if it works.

Comment: @V.K.authorofHiFile `scanLine` is the pointer to the new QImage data so I de-reference it with `*scanLine` to assign the pixel value from my container. Then I increase the pointer location with post `++` for the next pixel location. I edited my code as `scanLine` was a 32 bit pointer while I was assigning 16 bit data.

Comment: I see that. But `scanline` is a pointer to `image` data. And then you assign it to a value of a pixel from the same `image`. Unless I am missing something very obvious, this does not make sense to me. With this line `uint16_t *scanLine = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t *>(image.scanLine(row));` you get a pointer to `image` data. And with this line `*scanLine++ = image.data()[pixel++];` you just copy the pixel value from `image` to the same `image`. Since the image data is probably uninitialized, this may lead to the problem you observe.

Comment: I see the confusion, totally my fault, I accidentally used the same variable name in the code above. I'll update it, but it should be  `*scanLine++ = xray_image.data()[pixel++];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me (below is just fragments):

```
class Widget : public QWidget
{
private:
    QImage m_image;
    QImage m_newImage;
    QGraphicsScene *m_scene;
    QPixmap m_pixmap;
};
...
m_image.load("your/file/path/here");
m_newImage = m_image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_Grayscale8);

m_pixmap.convertFromImage(m_newImage);
m_scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
m_scene->addPixmap(m_pixmap);
m_scene->setSceneRect(m_pixmap.rect());

ui->graphicsView->setScene(m_scene);
```

Based on your OP, you probably want to render it differently. graphicsView is just a QGraphicsView defined in design mode.